# Unit testing subclasses which refer to each other

Tags: java, unit-testing

In Java I have the abstract class `Place`, with two concrete subclasses `Area` and `Level`; a `Level` must have a parent `Area`.  But in trying to make unit tests for `Level`, I don't want to have create a full-fledged instance of `Area`.  I see two ways of dealing with this:

1) Create an interface `IPlace`, extended by interface `IArea`, which `Place` and `Area` implement.  Then create a `MockArea` class which implements `IArea`, and pass that to `Level` when testing it.

2) Use a mocking framework which will automatically create mock objects for me.

Which way is better?  Or is there a third way to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason that `Level` must know that `Area` is an `Area` and not a `Place`?

Comment: 2) is imo easier (http://code.google.com/p/powermock/ , http://code.google.com/p/mockito/)

Comment: One `Level` can't be inside another `Level`, only inside an `Area`.

Comment: You should avoid 'which is better' questions. If you've already considered an approach, why is it insufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not giving us the reason why you don't want to create a full-fledged `Area`, but lets assume it does something difficult to test, like connect to a DB or read a file or something.  Those are dependencies that it has.  Dependency Injection is the answer.

For example, let's say `Area` does this in its constructor:

```
public Area() {    
    //get db connection
    //do something with db connection
}
```

Now when you create a `Level`, it'll connect to a DB.  Here's how you'd rewrite the constructor to use Dependency Injection:

```
public Area(Connection con) {    
    //do something with db connection
}
```

Now, when you create a `Level`, you can give it a fake `Connection` and are able to test your `Level`.

Now you can use a mocking framework to make a fake `Connection`.  I recommend Mockito.

Comment: `Area` doesn't do anything expensive.  It's just that I'm new to unit testing and everything I've read says to replace all dependencies with mock objects.

Comment: @MatthewCline I don't consider a parent to be a dependency in the bad sense.  Just test the public methods in `Level` in your `LevelTest` and the public methods in `Area` in `AreaTest`.  Make sure you're not testing the same thing twice.  You're good to go.

Comment: Well, it *can* cause problems if the parent is poorly designed.  I've given an example of a poorly designed parent.  As long as you're not in that situation, it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

As you've written it, I'd suggest using a mocking framework.

Dependency Injection is great. Using it lets your classes state in an obvious way what types of things they need to interact with. If done properly, the need for mocked objects is often unavoidable. Get used to working with a mocking framework. I like Mockito personally.